# Tela branca com react-native

Tags: react-native

Estou inicializando um projeto com react-native , porém após dar os seguintes comandos:

```
react-native init projectName
react-native run-android
```

Me deparo não com a tela de inicialização do react-native no emulador (Genymotion) ou no celular via USB, mas com uma tela totalmente branca,sem nenguma informação ou nenhum erro acusado. A mesma não altera de forma alguma,nem com reload do projeto,ou alteração no código fonte.
Alguem ja passou por essa situação ou sabe como me ajudar?

> A versão do react-native-cli : 2.0.1

Comment: Se o metro bundler não iniciou com o comando run-android, inicie-o com o comando `npm start` ou `yarn start`. Feche a app e abra novamente a partir do celular, deve resolver.

Comment: Ja fz isso várias vezes e não resolve,nada resolve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para resolver comece criando uma pasta **assets** dentro da pasta **android/app/src/main**.

Logo após, execute o comando:

```bsh
$ react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/
```

Agora, feche as abas do terminal e rode react-native run-android novamente.

[Docs RocketSeat](https://docs.rocketseat.dev/ambiente-react-native/errors/android)

Answer (score 0):

Remova a pasta ***node_modules*** e em seguida a reinstale digitando os seguintes comandos:

```
yarn install
```

ou

```
npm install
```

na sequência, execute novamente o seu projeto com o comando `react-native run-android` por exemplo.

Answer (score -1):

Isso acontece muito comigo, o que eu faço (coisa mais simples do mundo) não precisa rodar nenhum código.

1. Vá em Configurações do celular
2. Vá até aplicativos e abra a tela de configurações do seu app
3. Toque em armazenamento e limpe os dados **(TUDO)**
4. Abre app novamente, o Metro Bundler vai recarregar e vai aparecer tudinho